# Как изменить язык сайта на CMS OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

У меня в настройках магазина поставлен русский язык [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на сайте, всё равно английский

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В локализации тоже русский стоит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Убедитесь, что русский язык есть в папке `\catalog\language\ru-ru`.

2) Убедитесь, что сама тема поддерживает мультиязычность. Так как очень часто встречал темы только с английским языком.

3) Сбросьте кеш модификаторов, а если у вас opencart3 то сбросьте кеш полностью.

Если это не помогло, идём в `Система - Локализация - Языки`, там у вас будет список языков. Выставьте русский язык в качестве языка по умолчанию, а другие языки выключите.